# Using python multiprocessing.Lock as an argument type in mypy

Tags: python, multiprocessing, type-hinting, mypy

I have a python function that takes in a multiprocessing.Lock object as an input and uses the acquire and release functions on it. Evaluating it with mypy returns the error `Function multiprocessing.Lock" is not valid as a type`. How can I properly annotate this function?

Answer (score 5):

`Lock` is actually a plain function that returns a `_LockType`, which is defined as `_LockType = synchronize.Lock`, so you can do:

```
from multiprocessing.synchronize import Lock as LockBase

def func(lock: LockBase):
    pass
```

Although, the fact that they have `_LockType` as module private suggests they're treating it as an implementation detail that may change in the future, so be careful.

---

There's also this comment block above where `_LockType` is defined:

```
# The following type aliases can be used to annotate the return values of
# the corresponding functions. They are not defined at runtime.
#
# from multiprocessing import Lock
# from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
# if TYPE_CHECKING:
#     from multiprocessing import _LockType
# lock: _LockType = Lock() 
. . .
_LockType = synchronize.Lock
```

Answer (score 0):

For `multiprocessing` factory functions `Lock()` and `RLock()`, there are at least corresponding classes in the `multiprocessing.synchronize` submodule.

```py
from multiprocessing.synchronize import Lock as LockT, RLock as RLockT
```

The situation is worse in the closely related `threading` package, which might need to solve this internally, but till that's done, one can get away with defining a little [protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocols.html) for the two locks:

```py
class _LockType(contextlib.AbstractContextManager, typing.Protocol):
    def acquire(self, blocking: bool = ..., timeout: float = ...) -> bool: ...
    def release(self) -> None: ...


def ensure_lock(lock: _LockType | None) -> _LockType:
    return threading.Lock() if lock is None else lock

lock1 = ensure_lock(None)
lock2 = ensure_lock(Lock())
rlock = ensure_lock(RLock())
lock1.acquire()
lock1.release()  # mypy (1.7.1) is happy about all of the above
```

This protocol would be universally suitable for the locks from both the `threading` and `multiprocessing` packages, but it's not, because the [`multiprocessing.Lock.acquire`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock.acquire) has `block` as the 1st argument, while [`threading.Lock.acquire`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.acquire) has `blocking`. I wonder if that's intentional.